# API image not being displayed in list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I know there are several questions with this issue but mine is different.

I trying to display an image in my Flatlist card that is coming from an API. [However it is not showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAnsk.png)

BUT...when I display this image in another part of my code (in an Autocomplete list) using the same code basically, it works. Also, when I try an url from an image on the Web, [it displays inside the flatlist correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJCFm.png)

Here's my Flatlist code:

```js
   <FlatList
            data={this.state.myGamesArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Card>
                <CardItem>
                  <View>
                    <Image
                  style={styles.gameImage}
                  source={{uri: item.background_image}}
                  />   
                  </View>
                </CardItem>
                <CardItem>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.usergameText}>
                      {item}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </CardItem>
             </Card>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
          />
```

Here is my Autocomplete code in which I use the same image bracket-thingy

```js
<View style={styles.iconContainer} >
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query:                          item.name})}
              
                  style={styles.autocompleteList} >
                <View>
                  <Image
                  style={styles.gameImage}
                  source={{uri: item.background_image}}
                  />   
                </View> 
                
                <Text style={styles.gameText}>
                  {item.name} 
                </Text>
                
              </TouchableOpacity>    
            </View>
```

I ran console.item(item.background_image) both inside the Flatlist(first snippet) and the Autocomplete list (Second snippet). [The first shows 'undefined'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0zy2.png) and [the second it shows all the URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO4g1.png)

App.js full code:

```js
/*This is an example of AutoComplete Input/ AutoSuggestion Input*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Image, FlatList, Alert, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import { Button, List, Container, ListItem, Card, CardItem, Header, Item } from 'native-base';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons'
//import Autocomplete component
 
//const API = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=1';
//Demo base API to get the data for the Autocomplete suggestion
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Initialization of state
    //films will contain the array of suggestion
    //query will have the input from the autocomplete input
    this.state = {
      myGamesArray: [],
      games: [],
      query: '  ',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //First method to be called after components mount
    //fetch the data from the server for the suggestion
    fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=1&platforms=18', {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "495a18eab9msh50938d62f12fc40p1a3b83jsnac8ffeb4469f"
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        const { results: games } = json;
        this.setState({ games });
        //setting the data in the games state

      });
  }

  findGame(query) {

    let i;
    //method called everytime when we change the value of the input
    if (query === '') {
      //if the query is null then return blank
      return [];
    }
 
    const { games } = this.state;
    //making a case insensitive regular expression to get similar value from the film json
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    //return the filtered game array according the query from the input

    
    return games.filter(game => game.name.search(regex) >= 0);
  }  

  AddItemsToArray = () => {
    
    var i
    
    //verifica se input esta vazio
    if (this.state.query === '') {
      return Alert.alert('Voce não selecionou um jogo')
    }

    //VERIFY IF GAME IS IN THE ARRAY
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.games.length - 1; i++) {

      if (this.state.query !== this.state.games[i].name) {
        if (i === this.state.games.length - 2) {
          return Alert.alert('Este jogo nao existe')
        }
        else {
          continue
        }
      } else {
        break
      }
    }

    //verifica repetido
    if (this.state.myGamesArray.includes(this.state.query)) {
      
      return Alert.alert('Este jogo já foi adicionado')
    }
    else {
      //Adding Items To Array.
      this.setState(prevState => {
        const { myGamesArray, query } = prevState;
        return {
          myGamesArray: [...myGamesArray, query.toString()],
        };
      },
        // Use setState callback to alert with the updated state
      );
    }
  }
  
 
  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const games = this.findGame(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          Keyboard.dismiss()
         }}
      >
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <View style={styles.listContainer}
          >
            <FlatList
            data={this.state.myGamesArray}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                console.log(item.background_image),
              <Card style={{flexDirection:'row',paddingEnd:100}}>
                <CardItem cardBody>
                  <View>
                    <Image
                  style={styles.listImage}
                  source={{uri: item.background_image}}
                  />   
                  </View>
                </CardItem>
                <CardItem>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.usergameText}>
                      {item}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.usergameText}>
                      Playstation 4
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </CardItem>
             </Card>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
          />
        </View>
        
        <View>
        <Header span
          style={styles.header}>
          <Autocomplete
          inputContainerStyle={{borderColor:'transparent'}}
          style={styles.autocompleteInput}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          //data to show in suggestion
          data={games.length === 1 && comp(query, games[0].name) ? [] : games}
          //default value if you want to set something in input
          defaultValue={query}
          /*onchange of the text changing the state of the query which will trigger
          the findGame method to show the suggestions*/
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="  Adicione os jogos que você tem"
          //This below is the 'list' of autocomplete options
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                 
            //you can change the view you want to show in suggestion from here
            //I GET ERROR WHEN TRYING TO ERASE (PS4) IN TEXT BOX ***NEED TO CHECK THIS
            <View style={styles.iconContainer} >
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.name})}
                  style={styles.autocompleteList} >
                <View>
                  <Image
                  style={styles.gameImage}
                  source={{uri: item.background_image}}
                  />   
                </View>           
                <Text style={styles.gameText}>
                `${item.name}` 
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>    
            </View>

          )}
          />
          </Header>
          </View>
        
           <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addButton}
          onPress={() => this.AddItemsToArray()}
        >
           <Entypo name="plus" size={50} color="#fff" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
  },
  autocompleteInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderColor: '#7843FF',
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 70,
    borderRadius:10,
  },
  autocompleteList: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth:0.5,
    borderColor: '#7843FF',
    paddingVertical: 5,

    paddingRight: 60,
  },
    listContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    top:150,
    flexDirection:'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderColor: '#7843FF',
  },
  gameText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight:30,
    marginVertical:10,
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'left',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  usergameText: {
    fontSize:15,
    textAlign: 'left',
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    color: '#000',
  },
  gameImage: {
    flex: 3,
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    marginLeft:10,
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
  listImage: {
    flex: 3,
    height: 110,
    width: 90,
    marginLeft:0,
  },
  addButton: {
    height:50,
    width: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 371,
    top: 71,
    backgroundColor: '#7843FF',
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    borderBottomRightRadius:10,
  },
  usergameImage: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor:'#67E6DC'
  }
});
export default App;
```

Comment: can you console item inside flatlist?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: Can you print the <item> of FlatList ....
 <FlatList
            data={this.state.myGamesArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
            console.log(item)
              <Card>
   ........
      .......
    </Card>
})}

Comment: Understood...ok so when I did that, it returned me only the game name, in this case 'item.name'

Comment: that means in <item> object <background_image> is missing, that's why image rendering a null component as uri is null

Comment: But why when I run console.item(item.background_image) inside the autocomplete container, it returns me all the URIs. And when I use 'console.item(item.background_image)' inside the Flatlist it returns me UNDEFINED

Comment: From where you are getting item inside your autocomplete container,

Comment: From the same place as the flatlist, the Games API. I updated my question to add the screenshots of console.log

Comment: Sorry, you are doing something wrong... debug before rendering into ui

Comment: I debugged everything to make the code render to the UI so far...how can item.background display a link in the autocomplete list and display undefined in the Flatlist? It's the same piece of code and it's coming from the same API